# Dealing with asynchronous callbacks in Java

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, openfeint

One of my OpenFeint methods to recover leaderboard data needs an asynchronous callback to a method that is supposed to modify one of my local variables (using a wonderful hack). My problem now is that once the CB is called the execution continues and, as the score value has not changed *yet* it returns a nullPointer. Any way to make everything synchronize or return the callback value from the main function?

```
private long getScoreLeaderBoard(String idLeaderBoard) {
    for (Leaderboard l : OpenFeintX.leaderboards) {
        if (l.name == null)
            break;
        if (l.resourceID().equalsIgnoreCase(idLeaderBoard)) {
            final Score s[] = new Score[1];
            l.getUserScore(OpenFeint.getCurrentUser(),
                    new Leaderboard.GetUserScoreCB() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Score score) {
                            s[0] = score;
                        }
                    });
            if (s[0] != null) // If user has no score onSuccess get a null
                return s[0].score;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Callback definition: http://m.the9.com/ioshelp/Android_en/doc/com/openfeint/api/resource/Leaderboard.GetUserScoreCB.html

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onPostExecute` of the AsyncTask and do what you need to do in there

Comment: It doesn't have one :( http://m.the9.com/ioshelp/Android_en/doc/com/openfeint/api/resource/Leaderboard.GetUserScoreCB.html

Comment: The onSuccess cannot return the value for an upper method like getScoreboard, that's why I am using the local vble. onSuccess takes some time to run, meanwhile the execution continues and gets to the return part.

Answer (score 0):

If your method can stand to block while the asynchronous callback is executing, you could have it create a `CountDownLatch` like this:

```
private long getScoreLeaderBoard(String idLeaderBoard) {
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ...
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Score score) {
                        s[0] = score;
                        cdl.countDown();
                    }
    ...
        cdl.await();
        return s[0].score;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this stop my application for a second? I need this method to be run as fast as possible because it is part of a game.

Comment: if `getScoreLeaderBoard` is executed on the UI thread - yes. It waits until `onSuccess` happens

Comment: It is an answer, but it will probably won't be optimal :/ I'll give it a spin, though.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
private long getScoreLeaderBoard(String idLeaderBoard) { /* takes long */ }
```

make it

```
private void requestScoreLeaderBoardUpdate(String idLeaderBoard) { /* takes long */ }
```

and put the code that handled the returnvalue of getScoreLeaderBoard in (or call the method of it from) `onSuccess`.

That way you don't have to wait and block your thread.

You can also let your Activity implement `Leaderboard.GetUserScoreCB` and then it's like having another `onCreate`, `onClick`, ... like method.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements Leaderboard.GetUserScoreCB {

    private void requestScoreLeaderBoardUpdate(String idLeaderBoard) {
        // ..
        l.getUserScore(OpenFeint.getCurrentUser(), this /* your activity */);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Score score) {
        s[0] = score;
        // do anything you want with the new score here
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your idea but using a second method parameter long which is the one being changed, but the execution is still too fast and I get the nullPointer.

Comment: It's not to fast - it is not(¹) possible to get the result immediately even if the asynchronous thread does nothing but write the result into your variable. That is simply because the thread that calls `l.getUserScore` keeps executing until it returns the untouched variable. (¹) There is a chance that the scheduler stops executing the calling thread and lets the other one execute before you hit `return` but that depends on pure luck. The only way you can be sure that you don't return `null` is to explicitly stop the calling thread from executing (which is what `cdl.countDown()` does)

Comment: Sounds like you need to redesign a bit if these solutions don't work.  If your native/wrapper/handler call chain really needs the score to be returned to it, maybe the best you can do is to use the most-recently-cached score, and hopefully there's a way to notify the API that there's an updated score, once your asynchronous callback executes and the score has changed.  If not, I would look for examples of how other people use the API, or perhaps look for a Feint developer forum...

Comment: OpenFeint forums are like a barren most of the time, and I always bother googling the answer before asking in SO :P Strikes me odd that this has not been done before and that the Android API does not have convenient synchronous functions that iOS has.

I may end up getting the score during load, caching new high scores and working with it from there as you said.